# When deploying find the property batch.job.configuration.file.dir

Tags: spring-batch-admin

On deploying spring batch with spring batch admin application getting the error for not defining the property `batch.job.configuration.file.dir` in the property file.
what is use of defining this property ?

Answer (score 0):

In Admin API, xml file - `configuration-context.xml` has below file poller where this property is being used,

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter directory="${batch.job.configuration.file.dir}" channel="job-configuration-files"
        filename-pattern=".*\.xml">
        <poller max-messages-per-poll="1" cron="5/1 * * * * *" />
    </file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Default value for this property in API is - `batch.job.configuration.file.dir=target/config` so property is defined by default and you might have some other issue in overall bootstrapping of application.

I have deployed my Spring Admin in Weblogic and code has automatically created this directory under `base_domain` directory.

Property is mandatory and I guess, you have to also make sure that application user has rights to create that directory if that doesn't already exist.

I have not used this property but guess this part is being used in `Files` section of screen as shown below,

[image]

Explanation about File Tab is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/reference/configuration.html)

My screen shot above is from Angular Version of Spring Batch Admin.